# Grunt Uglifying Fatal error: Unexpected character ''

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-uglify

This is my test time trying Yeoman. I followed the very simple steps to install and setup my webapp with `yo webapp`

Did install a 3rd party JS library (skrollr) with bower.

Besides that its pure html/js/scss edits.

But when I run `grunt --force`, I get the below error and cannot proceed.

```
Running "modernizr:dist" (modernizr) task

Enabled Extras
>> shiv
>> load
>> cssclasses

Looking for Modernizr references

in dist/styles/main.css
>> svg

Downloading source files
cache modernizr-latest.js
cache modernizr.load.1.5.4.js

>> Generating a custom Modernizr build
>> Uglifying
Fatal error: Unexpected character ''
```

I have no idea where that came from. Any one has any idea how to resolve this?

If you're wondering why I used --force its due to these insignificant errors:

```
app/scripts/main.js
  line 4   col 3   Expected 'var' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 3.
  line 5   col 3   Expected 'var' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 3.
  line 7   col 3   Expected '$' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 3.
  line 9   col 3   Expected 'var' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 3.
  line 10  col 7   Expected 'render' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 13  col 7   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 9 instead at 7.
  line 14  col 3   Expected '}' to have an indentation at 5 instead at 3.
  line 9   col 11  'skrollr' is not defined.
  line 4   col 15  'winWidth' is defined but never used.
  line 9   col 8   's' is defined but never used.
  line 10  col 28  'data' is defined but never used.

✖ 11 problems
```

**Update:**
Just tried with a fresh `yo webapp` then `grunt` its having the same problem.

Comment: Same problem of mine one, have you find a solutions now?

Comment: You might want to check the issue here: https://github.com/Modernizr/grunt-modernizr/issues/96. I'm didn't test it cause I didn't have to use it again. Or you can just omit modernizr when it prompts you when you create a new app.